# Bootstrap Checkbox Orange Background and Blue background on inspect element

Tags: bootstrap-4

My checkbox is orange and blue in the same time.
When I inspect element it is blue.
I use bootstrap in project.

[Checkboxes when open browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itHho.png)

[Checkboxes when inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b8zP.png)

I tried reload cache, restart project and !important styles.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add some code, we can't help you without seeing what's causing that